# How to fix Kali NetHunter app crashing every time?

Tags: applications, root-access, stock-android, crashes, magisk

Kali NetHunter app is crashing on a *rooted* Android. Root installed with **Magisk** and Kali NetHunter installed with **nethunter-generic-arm64**.

Phone details: Redmi Note 11 (MIUI 13 - Android version 11)

I'm opening the NetHunter app - it opens for first time - takes **location** & **storage permission** - it *exits* (**closes app**) *automatically* - till here is fine, everything goes as per many tutorials show - then after reopening, it **asks for root permission** - *after giving root permission it **again closes*** - then for the last time when we open the **Kali NetHunter App** *(latest version - tested with both the APKs - one which gets per-installed while installing from Magisk and generic zip file *&* one downloaded and installed from NetHunter store)* - it shows black screen and then exits after few seconds.

Someone have solution for this?

Here is a issue related to it, that I can relate or is same as mine a bit: [Gitlab issues](https://gitlab.com/kalilinux/nethunter/apps/kali-nethunter-app/-/issues/286)

(another issue - not so relatable but could help : [not so helpful issue](https://gitlab.com/kalilinux/nethunter/build-scripts/kali-nethunter-project/-/issues/1232))

***Update***
OLD version (specifically v2019.1, [Github repo](https://github.com/offensive-security/nethunter-app)) the NetHunter app is working - means not crashing (but not able to download chroot- says some Javax...SSl... error) - I haven't got any version from 2020 but after v2021.4 nothing is working.

**[Download Log](https://anonfiles.com/Vb4485W1xb/logcat_log)**

Comment: The first step in fixing a bug or bypassing the problem is understanding why and what happens. I would recommend to check logcat if you see an exception or a problem. One the the cause has been identified you can try to bypass the problem or open an Gitlab issue that has the chance of being fixed.

Comment: I have already created an issue on their official [Gitlab repo](https://gitlab.com/kalilinux/nethunter/apps/kali-nethunter-app/-/issues/315), but don't have any response.
I'll surely check `logcat` and share the log here.

Comment: Without any debugging details the chance of your issue is very low that it will be resolved. Tom my experience issues without debugging details are mostly not resolved, unless some developer has very similar device and thus is able to reproduce the issue. So if you want the issue t be resolved you have to provide more detailed debugging info and logcat is the very basic information. As you have a rooted device logcat shouldn't be a problem for you.

Comment: Here is the logcat's log [download file](https://anonfiles.com/b4g742W0xb/logcat_log) (size:8.62mb). The log is captured from the steps mentioned in problem description till last (apps crashes)

Comment: And how should we know when the error occurred? You have posted a logcat that covers a few weeks instead of just that part when the error occurred. Clear the logcat using `logcat -c` then start logcat, reproduce the error search the error in logcat based on the shown time and extract it and add it to your issue.

Comment: thanks to telling - I'm new to use `logcat`, here is the new log [download link](https://anonfiles.com/Vb4485W1xb/logcat_log) - one more update the OLD version (specifically v2019.1, [github repo](https://github.com/offensive-security/nethunter-app)) the **Nethunter app** is working - means not crashing (but not able to download chroot- says some `javax...SSl...` error) - I haven't got any version from 2020 but after v2021.4 nothing is working!!\

Comment: The StackOverflowError starting at 64949 looks very strange. I would add the logcat starting with that line to your issue at Github. The rest is up to the Nethunter app developers.

Comment: I have created an issue on the gitlab - on official repo of nethunter app!
here is the link - [redirect](https://gitlab.com/kalilinux/nethunter/apps/kali-nethunter-app/-/issues/315) - you can also refer to this also [other similar issue](https://gitlab.com/kalilinux/nethunter/apps/kali-nethunter-app/-/issues/306)

Comment: Solution for this you may try this https://youtu.be/WQuGGlcuZa0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was of permissions - to solve the issue, run the following commands in **AndroidSU**

```
pm grant com.offsec.nethunter android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION 

pm grant com.offsec.nethunter android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION

pm grant com.offsec.nethunter android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

pm grant com.offsec.nethunter android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

pm grant com.offsec.nethunter com.offsec.nhterm.permission.RUN_SCRIPT 

pm grant com.offsec.nethunter com.offsec.nhterm.permission.RUN_SCRIPT_SU

pm grant com.offsec.nethunter com.offsec.nhterm.permission.RUN_SCRIPT_NH

pm grant com.offsec.nethunter com.offsec.nhterm.permission.RUN_SCRIPT_NH_LOGIN
```

*The above commands are given by developer of NetHunter App, @yesimxev. You can check [the discussion on GitLab](https://gitlab.com/kalilinux/nethunter/apps/kali-nethunter-app/-/issues/306).*

You can also check this video, [Gdrive link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-5DN66pL2_uk7qzVk8st6l9eiTYSlvPz/view?usp=sharing), to see what was the problem.